# Python3: help - script over complicated

Tags: python

Ive just started python yesterday and tried to make a randomized fighting game for bets with friends. I think this script could be alot shorter, but i dont know how. Ive just googled everything. plr1_hit and plr2_hit are mostly the same. Is there a way to make it just one thing? Like i said, im fairly new to python. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
import random
import time
dmg = random.randrange(1, 40)
plr2_health = 100
plr1_health = 100
plr2_live = True
plr1_live = True

def plr1_hit():
  global plr1_health
  global plr2_health
  global plr2_live
  dmg = random.randrange(1, 40)
  plr2_health = plr2_health - dmg
  if plr2_health < 1:
    plr2_live = False
    print("-----------------")
    print("PLAYER 1 LAYS DOWN THE FINAL PUNCH")
    print("Player 2 had died. Player 1 wins!")
  else:
    print("-----------------")
    if dmg < 30:
      if dmg < 15:
       if dmg < 5:
         hit = "pokes"
       else:
         hit = "slaps"
      else:
       hit = "punches"
    else:
      hit = "DESTROYS"
    print("player 1 " + hit + " player 2")
    print("--")
    print("--")
    print("Damage done:")
    print(dmg)
    print("--")
    print("Player 1 health:")
    print(plr1_health)
    print("Player 2 health:")
    print(plr2_health)
    print("-----------------")

def plr2_hit():
  global plr1_health
  global plr2_health
  global plr1_live
  dmg = random.randrange(1, 40)
  plr1_health = plr1_health - dmg
  if plr1_health < 1:
    plr1_live = False
    print("-----------------")
    print("PLAYER 2 LAYS DOWN THE FINAL PUNCH")
    print("Player 1 had died. Player 2 wins!")
  else:
    print("-----------------")
    if dmg < 30:
      if dmg < 15:
       if dmg < 5:
         hit = "pokes"
       else:
         hit = "slaps"
      else:
       hit = "punches"
    else:
      hit = "DESTROYS"
    print("player 2 " + hit + " player 1")
    print("--")
    print("--")
    print("Damage done:")
    print(dmg)
    print("--")
    print("Player 1 health:")
    print(plr1_health)
    print("Player 2 health:")
    print(plr2_health)
    print("-----------------")


while plr1_live == True and plr2_live == True:
  plr1_hit()
  time.sleep(5)
  if plr1_live == True:
    plr2_hit()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty natural place to use a class for your players. If you've not learned anything about Object Oriented Programming yet, this may seem complicated, but it's not really all that bad (though you might want to read [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)). A class is a convenient way to store some data (like the health of a player) along with some methods, which are functions that operate on that data.

Here's how I'd modify your `plrX_hit` functions so they were implemented by a single `hit` method of a `Player` class:

```
class Player: 
    def __init__(self, name):   # the __init__ method sets up an instance
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100       # save the player stats as attributes, rather than globals
        self.alive = True

    def hit(self, hitby):       # this works like your functions, self gets hit by hitby
      dmg = random.randrange(1, 40)
      self.health -= dmg
      if self.health < 1:
        self.alive = False
        print("-----------------")
        print(f"{hitby.name} LAYS DOWN THE FINAL PUNCH")    # use the name variables
        print(f"{self.name} has died. {hitby.name} wins!")  # rather than hardcoding
      else:
        print("-----------------")
        if dmg < 30:
          if dmg < 15:
           if dmg < 5:
             hit_descr = "pokes"
           else:
             hit_descr = "slaps"
          else:
           hit_descr = "punches"
        else:
          hit_descr = "DESTROYS"
        print(f"{hitby.name} {hit_desc} {self.name}")
        print("--")
        print("--")
        print("Damage done:")
        print(dmg)
        print("--")
        # the last part of the function, printing the health of both players,
        # is moved out of the method, because it was always in a specific order
        # (not related to who hit who).

player1 = Player("Player 1")   # here we create two instances of the Player class
player2 = Player("Player 2")

while player1.alive and player2.alive:  # you never need == True, just use the value
  player1.hit(player2)
  print("Player 1 health:")
  print(player1.health)
  print("Player 2 health:")
  print(player2.health)
  print("-----------------")
  time.sleep(5)
  if player1.alive:
    player2.hit(player1)
    print("Player 1 health:")
    print(player1.health)
    print("Player 2 health:")
    print(player2.health)
    print("-----------------")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to write this shorter and a bit more elegant.
You said yourself, that the two methods are mostly the same, so that's a clear sign, that you could combine them. All you need for a general hit_func() is a parameter you send when the function is called. With this parameter you could specify which player is hit.
And when you call the function, you do this alternating with player1, then with player2, etc.
Maybe something like this:

```
activePlayer = player1
while plr1_live == True and plr2_live == True:
hit(activePlayer)
time.sleep(5)
# change the player that is hit
if activeplayer == player1:
activeplayer = player2
else:
activeplayer = player1
```

In the hit function you then could use the passed in activeplayer to decide which health to reduce and what messages to print, etc.

Even more convenient you could write it with a player class and two objects for the players. Then every player object could have a hit method and the necessary variables like health, alive, etc. With this approach you could get rid of your global variables easily, which usually should be avoided.

```
class Player:
def __init__(self, health):
    self.health = health
    self.alive = True

def hit(self):
    #generate random damage and reduce the health of self accordingly, etc
```

Then you can create two player instances and hit them as before in a loop like this:

```
player1 = Player(100)
player2 = Player(100)
while player1.alive and player2.alive:
    #call the hit method alternating for both players
```

I hope that helps and gives you some ideas for improvements and new things to learn.